# VSCodeの画面下パネルでタブ間を移動するショートカット

Tags: vscode

VSCodeの以下のような画面で、[問題][出力][ターミナル][ポート][デバッグコンソール]のタブを順々に移動するようなショートカットキーがないでしょうか。

各要素を開くショートカット(たとえば、Ctrl+Shift+Uなど)があるのは知っていますが、5種類のショートカットを覚えるのは大変です…

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Ctrl+何か (に続けて) Ctrl+1 〜 5 などはダメですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

前後のパネル移動用ショートカットは`View: Previous Panel View(workbench.action.previousPanelView)`および`View: Next Panel View(workbench.action.nextPanelView)`として用意されています。
標準でショートカットキーは割り当てられていないので、お好みのキーを割り当ててください。

[image: ショートカット設定画面の例]

参考資料: [VS Code 1.29 の気になった変更点](https://qiita.com/12345/items/6993dc21f310e1b5dd99#%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%91%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0)

下記は<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>と+<kbd>6</kbd>に上記のショートカットを設定し、さらに<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>から<kbd>4</kbd>に各タブへのショートカットを追加する`keybindings.json`の例です。

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+5",
        "command": "workbench.action.previousPanelView" 
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+6",
        "command": "workbench.action.nextPanelView" 
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+1",
        "command": "workbench.actions.view.problems",
        "when": "workbench.panel.markers.view.active" 
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+2",
        "command": "workbench.action.output.toggleOutput",
        "when": "workbench.panel.output.active" 
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+3",
        "command": "workbench.debug.action.toggleRepl",
        "when": "workbench.panel.repl.view.active" 
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+alt+4",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.toggleTerminal",
        "when": "terminal.active" 
    },
]
```